# Синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксис

Опять обращаюсь с предложением,которое надо проверить:

> Я не знаю, сколько их, монументов
> славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее
> пределами.

Теперь надо сделать синтаксический разбор.

Вот что получилось:

Я (подлеж-ее,), не знаю (ПГС), сколько их (уточняющее дополнение, выраженное местоимениями ?), монументов славы и  победы (согл. приложения, которые относятся к личному местоим.), в нашей (согл. определение) стране (обстоятельство места) и за её (согл. определен.) пределами (обст. места).

Предлоги, союзы, частицы не беру, с ними всё ясно. С частями речи тоже почти всё ясно. И ещё вопрос: нужна всё-таки запятая после слова "победы"?

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: А на Грамота.ру не пробовали обратиться?

Comment: Дима, можно не по теме? Если Вы хотите разобраться с синтаксисом, вот материал, который будет Вам интересен и полезен:
http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304703

Answer (score 1):

...сколько их, монументов славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее пределами" - это все является придаточным предложением, осложненным обособленным приложением "монументов славы и победы". В каждой из частей сложного предложения надо делать разбор по членам предложения

Comment: Мы ещё не проходили сложноподчинённые предложения.

Comment: Значит, пишите просто: сложное, состоит из двух простых, пишите, что учили.

Comment: Тогда вопрос  будет от местоимения "их"к осложнённому приложению "каких?"монументов славы и победы"?"

Comment: Да, только не к осложнённому, а распространённому

Answer (score 1):

*Я не знаю, сколько их, монументов славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее пределами.* - предл. повествоват., невоскл., сложное, сложноподчинённое, сост. из 2-х простых.

*Я не знаю* - главное, нерапростр., двусост. полное, неосложнённое. *Я* - подлеж, не знаю - ПГС.

*сколько их, монументов славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее пределами* - придаточное изъяснительное; распространённое, неполное двусоставное с пропуском сказуемого (находится, есть), осложнённое уточняющим распростр. соглас. приложением (монументов славы и победы) и однородными обстоятельствами места (в стране и за пределами).

*сколько их* - подлежащее; монументов каких? - *славы и победы* - несогл. определение; *в стране* - обст.; *нашей* - согл. опред.; *за пределами* - обст. места; *её* - определение, выраж. притяж мест.

Comment: Значит,запятая перед"сколько ",потому что это начало придаточного предложения? Спасибо!

Comment: И ещё один вопрос: Слово "монументов" подчеркиваем тоже как определение?Или это дополнение?

Comment: Сколько их, (кого именно?) - приложение, а приложение - особый вид определения, выраженный именем сущ., второе название, значит, подчёркиваем как определение всё: монументов славы и победы (как и причастный оборот), а вот внутри можно отдельно разобрать, но это уже лишнее, если учитель не давал такого задания.

Comment: Пять монументов есть в нашей стране. Подлежащее - 5 монументов. Разве "сколько их" не такое же подлежащее, выраженное количественным сочетанием, только вместо числительного и существительного - местоимения?

Comment: Да конечно же, это называется "поспешишь - людей насмешишь". Очень торопилась, ответила и убежала. Конечно, это я и имела в виду (сколько их - подлежащее), когда говорила о пропуске сказуемого. А потом уже писала, видимо, без головы, когда обозвала обстоятельством и дополнением, думала не о том. Так что извините, дорогие форумчане, что вызвала такую дискуссию на пустом месте. Зашла сегодня на форум - сама удивилась. Что ж, пора, видно, на покой, раз с головой дружба прекратилась. Сейчас поправлю, если это этично.

Comment: Людмила, но ведь глагол ''не знаю'' требует после себя дополнения.Как в этом предложении "сколько их'' может быть подлежащем?

Comment: А как может быть подлежащим: "Я не знаю, кто это пришёл"? Придаточное изъяснительное, заменяет дополнение, но присоединяется союзным словом, кот. является подлежащим. Всё корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Я практически во всём согласен с Людмилой… Не согласен с этим:

> сколько - обстоят. меры и степени
>
> их - дополнение

При таком подходе придаточное предложение окажется не только без сказуемого, но и без подлежащего.

На мой взгляд, **"сколько их" -- подлежащее**, выраженное количественно-именным сочетанием.

Comment: Слава, предложение без подлежащего не всегда бывает безличным. Неполное предложение - предложение, в котором пропущен один из членов, извсестных из ближайшего текста.
Но в данном примере отсутствует подлежащее, да и сказуемое не восстанавливается из предыдущего контекста.
Но и назвать " сколько их" подлежащем тоже нельзя. Подлежащее - субъект действия.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что нельзя мысленно ПРИПИСЫВАТЬ в предложение сказуемое, а потом называть предложение НЕПОЛНЫМ. Неполное предложение имеет строгое определение: пропущенный член должен быть точно назван в контексте. Приведем примеры: (1) "В нашей стране 5 монументов. Сколько монументов в нашей стране?" Здесь числовой оборот в роли ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕГО. Предложение ЭЛЛИПТИЧЕСКОГО вида (НЕ НЕПОЛНОЕ). (2) "Монументов много. Сколько их, монументов?" Здесь уже не пространственно-числовые, а просто числовые отношения. Предложение БЕЗЛИЧНОЕ, сказуемым является оценочно местоимение (сколько, много).

Comment: Вера, я правильно понял: предложение "В нашей стране 5 монументов" вы относите к неполному двусоставному?

Comment: Я думаю, что это эллиптическое предложение, а такие предложения отличаются от неполных. В них два компонента (подлежащее - дополнение, подлежащее - обстоятельство, обстоятельство - дополнение, сказуемое отсутствует, при этом его семантика ясна, но эту семантику выражает целая группа глаголов: В нашей стране (имеется, находится, располагается)5 монументов. Такие предложения по структуре и смыслу близки к неполным двусоставным, но всё-таки выделяются в отдельную группу.

Comment: А-а, да, вы правы.Но только в том предложении, которое приводите вы.Ср.: За спиной находится **/ расположен /** виден лес. В том контексте, который разбирается здесь - монументов славы и победы - приложение.

Answer (score 0):

А если немного отвлечься от школьных задач, то как правильно разобрать предложение?

"Я не знаю, сколько их, монументов славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее пределами".

Главный вопрос -  как  определить вид придаточного "сколько их". В грамматике выделяются   КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННО-БЫТИЙНЫЕ БЕЗЛИЧНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ:  "Времени хватает/не хватает. Сил прибавилось/убавилось. Снегу намело!"

Наверное, сюда же можно отнести такие предложения: Снегу много. Их много.  Это тоже количественно-бытийная оценка. Тогда "сколько" - это сказуемое в безличном предложении, а "их" - дополнение.

Как вы думаете?

Что касается школы, то о каком правильном разборе может идти речь, если школьники еще не изучали сложноподчиненные предложения. И тем более не стоит предлагать варианты, которые и филологами определяются неоднозначно.

Comment: Спасибо,я тоже так считаю.

Answer (score 0):

Знакомое предложение, его недавно предлагали для разбора, но вопрос был закрыт. Домашнее задание!

Оно, конечно, верно, но сам разбор интересный. Вот мой вариант ответа.

1. Грамматическая основа придаточного предложения: СКОЛЬКО (ИХ).

Это **односоставное безличное предложение**, при этом субъект (носитель признака) выражен формой Р.п. «их». И конечно же, ИХ – это дополнение.

2. **Сказуемое составное именное**, связка «быть» пропущена, именная часть выражена  относительным местоимением с количественным значением «сколько». Для сравнения: сколько их было, их было много (в прошедшем времени связка "было" присутствует).

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Безличные предложения иногда считают бессубъектными. Это неточно. Субъект (носитель признака или состояния) в таких предложениях есть и обычно выражен формой Д.п. или Р.п.

Меня же удивляет количество вариантов при разборе, но давно это было... **А как сегодня участники форума разберут это предложение?**